# Crystal detector power measurement and SWR measurement - How are they related?

Tags: power, measurement, crystal, detector

I'm researching the application and behavior of crystal detectors, like the [HP 423B](https://www.keysight.com/us/en/product/423B/low-barrier-schottky-diode-detector-10-mhz-to-12-4-ghz.html). I understand the core principle of a detector: extraction of the 'video' signal that is amplitude modulated on top of the carrier waveform, and power measurement of the RF signal, especially when the diode operates in the square law region.

However, there are 2 instances (related I assume) where SWR comes up.

The specification of the detector has the following:

> Maximum SWR: 1.15 (10 MHz to 4 GHz), 1.3 (4 GHz to 12.4 GHz)

My limited understanding of SWR is that it is the ratio maximum and minimum magnitude of a standing wave, caused by impedance mismatch and the resulting reflection of a transmitted signal.

In the context of a crystal detector, which SWR are they talking about?

In addition to that, the [operating manual of an Agilent 8473B Detector](https://xdevs.com/doc/HP_Agilent_Keysight/HP%208473%20Operating%20and%20Service.pdf) contains the following:

> The power applied to the detector can be either modulated or
> continuous wave (CW). If modulated at a 1,000 Hz rate, an SWR
> meter can be used as an indicator

Indeed, if you look at [the manual of an HP 415E SWR meter](https://xdevs.com/doc/HP/415E.pdf), there's quite a bit of content related to detectors and the SWR meter. I understand the 1000Hz: it just happens to be the operating point for which the the 415E can measure SWR.

But I don't understand the more fundamental reason of how why SWR measurement is used to measure power in this case.

I also don't understand how SWR specification of the detector and the usage of an SWR meter to measure power are related.

Answer (score 1):

I think I can answer the first part of your question, the SWR would be the SWR introduced by connecting the detector to your system. While it's impedance is nominally 50\$\Omega\$, there's going to be some slight mismatch. Pretty much anything you connect in line in an RF system is going to have some mismatch, even a simple connector, and it's going to vary with frequency. When you get up into UHF frequencies and above something as simple as the spacing between the center pin and housing of a connector can change the impedance and introduce standing waves. The SWR rating mentioned is simply the specifications for the maximum SWR you can expect the detector to introduce.

Comment: That makes sense. If so, then the two SWR mentions are unrelated. 
I'm starting to think that, for the second case, the SWR meter is not used to measure anything related to a standing wave, but that the RF signal is modulated full on/off with a square LF waveform in order to make it compatible with something you can measure with a SWR meter: the ratio between a minimum value. In this case: zero, when the RF signal is modulated completely off, and maximum when the RF signal is full on.